# Fill down rows randomly by Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the values on the range "A1:O1". 
Each Column has a unique value in this range.
I need help to develop a loop that will fill down 04 times on each column the same Top Value (Column Value). Below a Pseudo Code

```
Sub FillDownRowsRandomly()
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

 'RamdomRow=Total of 04 unique ramdom numbers
 'choosen from 01 to 06 {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 'meaning that in a loop of 6 interations, when fill down
 '2 will be Null or empty
 '
 For i = 1 To 15 'Columns "A" To "O"
     For j = 2 To 7 '
     '
     Cells(RandomRow, i).Value = Cells(1, i).Value
     Next j
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Below an Image where will be possible identify the result of the code.
Disregard the "Null" word written in the cells. I wrote that just to clarify that during the random loop, the code "ignored that cell".

[image: ImageShowingHowTheResultMightBe]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately is NOT that.
I edited the post including an image showing how will be the result of the CODE.
Please disregard the Null" written in the cells. It is just to clarify that during the random loop, the code "ignored that cell".

Comment: So you wish to choose from 1-6 on each column seperately or would the choice be the same for all columns, but all on random rows?

Comment: Random Rows with the Top Value as shown in the image.
The value of its respective column will be replicated 04 times on rows below, random positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
Sub FillDownRowsRandomly()

Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long

With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    For y = 1 To 15
        z = 0
        Do While z < 4
            x = Int((7 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
            If .Cells(x, y) <> .Cells(1, y) Then
                .Cells(x, y) = .Cells(1, y)
                z = z + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next y
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @JvdV
Can I ask you some changes? Is possible change from rows to columns?
FillColumnsRandomly()
Same concept. The repeatable values remain on Row#1 and the code will fill the cells leaping the columns as per random value (x) in a total of 10 rows.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Also, it seems like a new question you can post on SO. But you should definately close this one first. Click the check mark next to the answer that has best suited your problem to return the favor. @Luthius

Answer (score 0):

Loop the columns and randomly place the values till there are four in the six rows.

```
Sub FillDownRowsRandomly()
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:O7").ClearContents
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 15 'iterate the columns

    Do Until Application.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Resize(6), ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value) >= 4
        Dim j As Long
        j = Application.RandBetween(2, 7)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value
    Loop
Next i


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code. 
Can I as a little bit more of code?
The second loop will do almost the same on Range R1:W1
But will choose instead 04 will be 05 from a total of 06.
The end result will be a table generated by the combination of both loops where this table will contain 15 Columns and 06 Rows and the each Column has a distinct value.

Comment: @Luthius new question get new posts.  Try to modify on your own.  If you get errors come back and ask a new question with the code you tried and ask a specific question.