# Fill columns randomly by Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Recently I was helped with a code that fill down randomnly the cells based on Row#1 values. [Answered_Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135792/fill-down-rows-randomly-by-loop/58136440?noredirect=1#comment102847327_58136440). (Thanks to @JvdV and  @Scott Craner for assist me before.)

What I need to do now is almost the same, but the code will fill the cells leaping the columns as per random value (x) in a total of 10 rows. The repeatable values remain on Row#1.

Below the code provided on that post to fill down rows. I need now, as per picture, fill the columns.

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
For y = 1 To 15
    z = 0
    Do While z < 4
        x = Int((7 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
        If .Cells(x, y) <> .Cells(1, y) Then
            .Cells(x, y) = .Cells(1, y)
            z = z + 1
        End If
    Loop
Next y
End With
```

[Table_With_Sample_Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epPNq.png)

Comment: Just do the same thing with a variable for the column.

Comment: Can you give some sample?

Comment: I understand your point. I tried different codes but I got stuck.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub FillColumns01()
    For y = 1 To 15
    z = 0
    j = 1
    Do While z < 4
            x = Int((7 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
            If Cells(x, y) <> Cells(1, y) Then
                Cells(y + 1, j) = Cells(1, y)
                z = z + 1
                j = j + 1
            End If
    Loop
Next y
End Sub

Sub FillColumns02()
'Using a 3rd Loop
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer, j As Integer

For y = 1 To 10
    z = 0
    Do While z < 4
        For j = 1 To 15
            x = Int((7 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
            If Cells(x, y) <> Cells(1, y) Then
                Cells(j, x) = Cells(1, y)
                z = z + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Loop
Next y

End Sub
```